# node.js Template HTML Files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm fairly new to node.js and I'm wondering if there is a way to generate the HTML files from express post requests.

```
app.post('/getVideo', function(req, res) {
    fs.readdir('./videos', function(err, items) {
        var toSend = "<ul>";
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            toSend += "<li class='fileType' data-id='"+items[i]+"'>"+items[i]+"</li>";
        }
        toSend += "</ul>";
    });
});
```

This works, however it uses an empty HTML page.  Is there a way where I can provide an HTML page as a form of template, and input values into specific ids or something, much like an MVC.

I know I can push a page using:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/getVideos.html");
```

However, this then gets overwritten by any other res.sends.

I'm aware that you can do something like this with .NET and MVCs like React and Angular, I was just wondering if node had any module that allowed for something like this.

Thanks in advance,

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jade** one of the most popular templating engine for NodeJS.

http://jade-lang.com